# (How) can I get Microsoft NetMeeting to work on Windows 7 without using a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, netmeeting

I've tried compatibility mode and the troubleshooter and got it to install but running it (and just before "NetMeeting has been installed successfully."), it returns this error:

> **conf.exe - Entry Point Not Found**
>
> The procedure entry point ASN1PERDecZeroTableCharStringNoAlloc could not be located in the dynamic link library MSASN1.dll.

I noticed that in Windows XP MSASN1.dll is located in %SystemRoot%\system32\dllcache so I thought if I copy MSASN1.dll from Windows XP to it's equivalent folder in Windows 7 it might work, does anyone know he equivalent folder? Then again I tried removing MSASN1.dll from it's folder in Windows XP and NetMeeting still ran so maybe not but it's worth a try.

Edit: The reason I don't want to use a virtual machine is because I wan't to use remote desktop sharing to connect from Windows 2000 to Windows 7 and vice versa, if I used a VM I would only be able to connect to the guest Os within Windows 7 rather than Windows 7 its self, and, virtual machines take to long to stat especiually just to run one program.

Comment: Since the dll is a 32-bit file I would put it in the 32-bit WoW64 System32 folder.  Why are you against using a virtual machine, that would be the correct way, to run an unsupported program like this.

Comment: I can't find a WoW64 folder (my computer's 32 bit by the way), although I did find a wow32.dll. I'm against using a virtual machine because 1. they take too long to start and 2. because I want to use NetMeetings remote desktop sharing feature and if a ran it in a VM I would only be able to connect to the guest OS from the other computer rather than the host OS.

Comment: That is helpful information.  So just put the file in System32 in that case.  Windows 7 replaced NetMeetings I am sure, I would use that instead, sadly you might have to go the route of a third-party application if you want to support Windows 2000 which isn't support by Microsoft.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use TeamViewer, UltraVNC, LogMeIn or similar?